# Use runas with cmd /k and path containing spaces

Tags: powershell, runas

Here is the command I try to execute:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\user "cmd /k C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"
```

When i try to execute it I have the following error message:
`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

As the following commands work:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\user "C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"
cmd /k """C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"""
```

I also try this command:

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\user "cmd /k """"""C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"""""""
# bad syntax

runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\user "cmd /k \"C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe\""
# The term 'x86' is not recognized
```

I didn't manage to find the right used of double quotes to make my command run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the short pathname, e.g.

```
runas /netonly /user:DOMAIN\user "cmd /k C:\Progra~2\program.exe"
```

`dir /x` will give both the short and the long filename.

Comment: I didn't know the `dir /x` command to know the path short name. Thanks a lot, you solved my problem.